# Extend Android virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android

i'm thinking in something a la Appstore's Textsastic, this is, a full row of needed keys (parenthesis, slash, etc) right above the virtual keyboard, like it was an extention of it.

How can i accomplish something like that in Android?
Is there at least a way to have a listener when the virtual keyboard shows?

Comment: You'll have to re-implement the keyboard. As far as I know, there's no way to just add to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this article on how to [create an input method](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html).   You can't extend an existing keyboard without the code.  You could probably hack something together that would work in a single app, but not across all apps.